# Php Mysql - Create new category from category

Tags: php, mysql

I’m working on food delivery system. I want to create new category from category. I have successfully created category from a list of product. But now, I want to create new category as a food menu from the category that I have done before.
this is my product table:

```
####code | pro_name | price | pro_category####

1 | burger  |   3 | 1

2 | soda    |   1 | 2

3 | fries   |   2 | 3

4 | c.burger |  4 | 1
```

Then I create category table to make the food category:

```
####Cat_id | cat_title####
1   Burger

2   Drink

3   Adds on
```

But now, how I want to create the menus (new category) which the output will shows this:

```
####Set A      | Set B####
2 Burgers | 3 burgers

2 drinks | 3 drinks

1 adds on | 2 adds on
```

And the admin also can change the quantity of each item in the each set menu..
I hope u guys understand what I want to do..

Comment: Please update the post with your question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: It seems like you are giving your project task to SO users! SO is for help not for doing personal task @awang

Comment: actually i want to know or getting some idea how to get the output using mysql and php.. so far i already know how to link the product table in term to get the category of the product by using this:
$get_cat_pro = "select * from product where pro_category='$cat_id'";

but i dont know how to write the sql to get the output table.. or maybe i should create another table..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a table structure you could try something like this:

```
id | key   | quantity | product name
1  | menu1 | 2        | Burgers
2  | menu1 | 2        | Drinks
3  | menu1 | 1        | adds on
4  | menu2 | 3        | Burgers
5  | menu2 | 3        | Drinks
6  | menu2 | 2        | adds on
```

So, You could have a list of all the product with a quantity, and use the key (number/name) for the menu.

Comment: all right.. thanks. i get the idea. i'll try this later on